# fmt.Println calling Error instead of String()

Tags: go

I have this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type ErrNegativeSqrt float64

func (s ErrNegativeSqrt) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%f", float64(s))
}

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Cannot Sqrt negative number: %v", float64(e))
}

func Sqrt(x float64) (ErrNegativeSqrt, error) {
    if x < 0 {
        e := ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
        return e, e
    } else {
        return ErrNegativeSqrt(math.Sqrt(x)), nil
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

And the output of this code is

> Cannot Sqrt negative number: 1.4142135623730951 <nil>
>   Cannot Sqrt negative number: -2 Cannot Sqrt negative number: -2

When I have implemented the Stringer interface for the ErrNegativeSqrt, why is the fmt.Println invoking the Error() method instead of the String() method?

I am new to go, so I might be missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation states how the value is converted to a string](https://godoc.org/fmt):

> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

The `error` interface comes before `Stringer`.

A more idiomatic way to write the function is:

```
func Sqrt(x float64) (float64, error) {
  if x < 0 {
    return 0, ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
  }
  return math.Sqrt(x), nil
}
```

Comment: Any other way to make it print the regular string instead of the error message?

Comment: @Srisa: `fmt.Println(Sqrt(2).String())` ?

Comment: It's a two-argument return value, so that won't work.  But frankly, that reflects a problematic design in general.  Functions can return multiple values, so there's no real reason for your result item to also implement the error interface when you can just pass back an error itself (which you're doing, by literally passing the same item back twice).  Bad code smell is the problem here.